# Are there any tools that support resx localization refactoring in xaml?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml, resharper, globalization

For example, using resharper in c# code I can perform a 'Move to resource' refactor on a string literal.  Resharper will move the hard-coded string to a resx file and replace my c# with a reference to the strongly typed resource.  This is very useful when writing a globalized application.  I am looking for a tool with similar functionality but for xaml.

Comment: +1, Good question! Will be interesting to see the answers to this one

Comment: I've started another related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876950/are-there-localization-tools-which-spot-content-strings-in-xaml-wpf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ReSharper's Move to Resource actually does support XAML but only in WPF projects. Silverlight and WP7 are not currently supported.

Comment: Thanks!  How do I use the feature?  Ctrl r + o doesn't work which is what I have been using for c#.  I'm trying to use it in a WPF 4.0 project.

Comment: Is the refactoring available through Refactor this (Ctrl+Shift+R)?

Comment: yes it is!  Thanks!  You seem to need to use the Content attribute, ie   <Label Content="This can be moved to resx via Ctrl+Shift+R"/>     rather than   <Label>This won't be</Label>.  Yet again, ReSharper proves to be awesome!