# Are there localization tools which spot content strings in xaml/wpf?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml, globalization

When globalizing a wpf application with static resx classes, it's very easy to miss the odd label or button that has its `Content` property set to a hard coded string in a particular language, ie English.  These should of course be moved off to a `{x:Static ...}` so they can be localised for each culture.

Are there any tools which can spot this and warn you?  Built in to VS would be ideal, but I'm thinking that 'style cop' type build tools would do the job as well.

Comment: Why don't you use LocBaml tool? It doesn't require static strings and is launched at the end of development.

Comment: I'm a bit wary of the locbaml workflow, and its lack of tooling and support.  It seems more suited to a waterfall development process, where once coded, a screen doesn't change.  Would you go so far as to recommend it over the traditional resx approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[David Anson](https://dlaa.me/blog) posted just such a tool a few weeks ago. It's a [pseudo-localization](https://dlaa.me/blog/post/10121146) tool that alters all the strings defined in ResX files so that they stand out from static strings. It changes letters to their accented forms, and also adds padding to strings so you can test for layout changes in languages with longer translations.

Comment: That looks like a useful tool, I like the fact it also helps with layout issues.

Comment: This link is now dead